# what is the difference between tier and layer in c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I have difficulty in understanding difference between tier and layer in c#. In my project my team leader asked me do it in n-tier architecture I did sample form and showed to him and he said that's 3-layer architecture. What is the difference between layer and tier i am still confused.
I took two classes one for business logic, one for data acccess

```
class bll
{
   //code for business logic
}

class dll
{
   //code for connection string
}
```

one more .cs

Comment: Without more details, I'd say the terms are interchangeable. Maybe in some very specific context, there is a difference, but in this case I think you and your team leader are talking about the same thing. When in doubt, why not ask him instead of us?

Comment: [A previous similar question has some great answers.][1]

In short, a layer is logically separated while a tier is physically separated.
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182303/n-tiered-vs-n-layered-architecture-design

Answer (score 0):

There is no big difference between the 3-tier and 3-layered architecture but the difference is in the performance and place the components like BL,DAL and Presentation Layer. see below when i got doubt at the time of developing my project in 3-tier what i explored.

Layers of application may reside on the same physical computer(same tier) and the components in each layer communicates with the components of other layer by well defined interfaces.Layered architecture focuses on the grouping of related functionality within an application into distinct layers that are stacked vertically on top of each other.Communication between layers is explicit and loosely coupled.With strict layering, components in one layer can interact only with componentsin the same layer or with components from the layer directly below it.

Tiers architecture usually have atleast three separate logical parts,each located on separate physical server.Each tier is responsible with specific functionality.Each tier is completely independent from all other tier, except for those immediately above and below it.Communication between tiers is typically asynchronous in order to support better scalability.which may mean different assemblies such as DLL, EXE, etc. on the same server or multiple servers.