# What is the software architecture that best describes a windows application directly communicating to a database?

Tags: .net

What is the software architecture that best describes a windows application directly communicating to a database?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"? Using a provider-specific API? Utilizing the communication protocol directly? Writing to the files directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2-tier architecture

Comment: I thought it was 1-tier or n-tier.  So I guess it's 2-tier?  Thanks for your knowledge (:

Comment: Single-tier architecture is the notion of having the user interface of a web application, the middle ware and the data access all contained in one whole architecture. Usually in Software Engineer you break your application to make them more maintainable and sustainable. If you know that your software will not grow over time, you may want to do a single tier architecture.   http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_single-tier_architecture

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you read the answer to the question here: [whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers)  Many times the term tier is used synonymously with layer, in that a layer is a software architectural construct, and a tier represents a physical computer.  The concept of layers exists so that additional tiers can be introduced without changing the software.  If you use the SQLClient classes to access the data layer (i.e. the database) from a front end application the code in the front end application doesn't really care if the database is on the same machine or on a different machine.  When these two terms are used in this way you can refer to an application as being multi-layered but single-tiered, multi-layered or 2-tiered, or multi-layered and multi-tiered.  If your front-end application is running on one computer and the database is running on a second computer then your application is multi-layered and 2-tiered.  If your front-end application is running on the same computer as the database then the application would be multi-layered and single-tiered.

Answer (score 0):

I would have said client-server [seek wikipaedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) but 2-tier is also a valid description

Answer (score -2):

Once they were called single-tier systems.

Comment: Ok, and who's that moron that doesn't know what single-tier system is?