# 3-tier architecture in an asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have an asp.net project, I created three folders under the root. The folder names are: "UI", "Logical" and "DataAccess". The correspond codes are seperated into different folders.
For example, UI folder contains only presention, DataAccess contains how to retrieve dataset from database.

Can we say it is a three tie architecture?

Comment: The fact that you created some folders doesn't mean anything yet in terms of architectural pattern. You seem to have mentioned some, I quote, `corresponding codes` but without providing more information about this code your question hardly makes any sense.

Comment: Related posts : 1. [What is the difference between tier vs layer application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978991/what-is-the-difference-between-tier-vs-layer-application) 2. [What's the difference between “Layers” and “Tiers”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers) 3. [Layers vs. Tiers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmeier/archive/2008/09/06/layers-and-tiers.aspx)

Comment: Title says ASP.NET, tags say ASP.NET MVC. Which one are you talking about, sir? They're a little bit different when layering them.

Comment: It is asp.net web form application. I put mvc here just think mvc is 3 layer architectural, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following link it may help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36847/Three-Layer-Architecture-in-C-NET

Answer (score 0):

For me it is important to impose a physical separation to your layer.

So create library for Logical

So create library for DataAccess

And Presentation Project for  UI.

Nota :

That permit to easy your layer, without use all yours composants.

If you want re use just your Logical , you can reference just your layer.

You create a low coupling, it can reduce the impact of a bug in an application

...

Answer (score 0):

I found that this book helped me organise my layers correctly:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-NET-Architecting-Applications-PRO-Developer/dp/073562609X/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1348672396&sr=1-1