# Does my application missing app tier?

Tags: java, spring, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

Am new to programming. I have created a Spring MVC web application.
It has JSPs for the frontend, Spring MVC as the middleware component and for data part a request is made to webservice to fetch the data. The middleware component does not have too much business logic since the application itself and exists just for fetching data.

My friend says that my application is missing the application tier. Is this correct?
Currently I deploy my application in Tomcat and DB is Teradata. 
Am not using any app server(only web server).
So does this mean my application is missing the app tier? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your friend is thinking of a 3-tier application, then yours doesn't have the Web Tier, or in fact, you have combined the Web and App tiers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the logic implemented in your controllers. Usually JSPs an controllers are part of the view layer, business logic is in business layer an persistance layer is basically a database. This is called three tier application.

The logic in controllers should only care about how the data are presented to the user and should't do any operation on the data itself. Then you would have clean view layer.

There is no problem in having all business logic on the side of the webservice. Actually I would say this is quite common.

Comment: I think your comment confuses layers with tiers. There is a difference between the two. While tiers refer to the physical separation, layers is more of logical separation as in MVC. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers