# Is a simple ASP.NET site using SQL Server known as 2-Tier Architecture?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, architecture, 2-tier

Lets say I have a simple web application built in C#, which includes a few aspx pages and a web.config file that includes SQL Server database details.
Some of the aspx pages will call stored procedures from the database - either SELECT or INSERT queries, and forms authentication will be used.

From an Application Architecture point of view, would this be 2-Tier Architecture (Data Tier - Client Tier) or 3-Tier architecture (Client Layer - Business Layer - Data Layer) ?

It sounds to me like 2-Tier, but since aspx.cs is server side, would this be seen as the business layer?

Also, apologies if I shouldn't be asking this question here, but I can't remember the name of your sister site!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between "Layers" and "Tiers"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers)

Comment: As far as "sister" sites, there are lots of them.  Most likely you mean programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in my opinion what you described is a 2-tier architecture because there is not a business layer even though the code is server-side.  A business layer should contain all of your business objects and logic and your .cs pages would simply call those business objects.

I build most of my applications the same way: Asp.net front end calling SQL Server stored procedures for CRUD operations.  However if I ever went to a different database platform I would have to change A LOT of code because there is not a true business layer in place.  Lastly, a business layer will make your code more testable as well.

Sorry I can't help with the sister site question :)

Comment: You are correct that it is a 2-tier architecture.  However, it is not due to a lack of a business "layer".  Tiers and Layers are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The terms `Tier` and `Layer` are not synonymous.

A `Tier` is a "physical" separation in the application.  Each tier is a place where one or more layers are deployed and executed from.  This includes items such as a web server, database server, etc.  Note that the entirety of a 2 (or 20!) tier system may even be executed from a single machine.  For example, when the web server and database server are installed on the same hardware.

A `Layer` is a logical separation in the application and uses terms such as Presentation, Business Logic and Data Access to describe the various logical separations made in your app.

Systems can be n-Tier and n-Layer.

So, if you have a web application made up of 1 web server (running the app itself) and 1 database server (your DB server) then you have a 2-Tier application.  If the only separation in the application is where the table structures live, then it is most likely a 2 Layer application as well.