# Three tier architecture in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture, three-tier

I would like to know what does it mean to implement three tier architecture in asp.net mvc?

I have seen a lot of posts regarding this, which are mentioned in such a way. But I am so confused with it.
Does seperation of MVC Model to another solution called Business Layer known as implementing three tier architecture in mvc ? If not, what is the proper way of implementing three tier architecture in mvc?

**Type 1**
Presentation Tier: "Controllers and Views" from MVC Pattern.
Business Tier : "Model(Data)" from MVC Pattern.
Data Access Tier : Original Data Access Tier.

**Type 2**
Presentation Tier: Everything in MVC except model
Business Tier: Seperate the Model out
Data Access Tier: database itself

Answer (score 2):

It's more like this:

- **Presentation Tier**: Everyting related to MVC
- **Business Tier**: A separate
  *Core Domain Model* (it's **not** the 'M' from MVC). It may include a service
  layer to provide a clean interface over the domain model.
- **Data Tier**:
  The Database

[MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) itself is just a presentation-tier - specific pattern, and ASP.NET MVC is simply a framework for creating Web UIs.

A model in MVC is also called a *View Model*, which means it's only responsibility is to model the *View*; It transports data between the *Controller* and the *View* to keep them decoupled.
Do not confuse the model in MVC with the Domain Model pattern, which applies to the Business Tier.

Putting business logic into MVC viewmodels may work for the easier problems, or prototypes, but it won't be what they call a three-tier system.

[Microsoft Application Architecture Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650706.aspx) - a free e-book from Microsoft on how to design and structure your solutions and much more.

Comment: I added a link to a relevant e-book from Microsoft - it's available for free

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen a flat out best option for 3 tier architecture with MVC. It really comes down to what works best for you. In sharing how we implement the MVC architecture, it may not be the best, but what ever is the best way to go today, will be the 2nd best way tomorrow.

The web UI project contains the views and controllers -- presentation tier

In a separate project, create service classes that are called by the controllers -- business logic tier.

Model classes are also in this second project serving as a business object layer which links to the presentation tier.

Any services that require any interaction with the db are in separate classes in the second project. --data access layer.

Also, we have a services composition class that generates all or any specific services as needed. -- I would also relate this to the business logic layer.

For what we do, this works great.

Comment: This confuses [layers and tiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers)