# Three-tier architecture , ioT device in presentation layer?

Tags: architecture, three-tier

Its probably a strange question but iam asking myself where to put a ioT device in an architecture design when i have a three tier architecture.

Presentation, Business-Logic, Data

Now a webapplication is in presentation layer.
application server = business logic
database= data tier
But where should be a ioT device. There is no presentation or userinterface for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think your IoT device is not a presentation layer?  Are you gathering information from the outside world?  Are you presenting information to the outside world?  Yes?  Then that's a presentation layer.

Blinkenlights, sensors, switches, these are all the interface to your device.

If you IoT device does present or gather information, then why is it hooked up to your application?

Also, do not confuse Tier with Layer.  [They are different.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers)  Your IoT device may (and probably should) have multiple layers.