# How to prove that program has a layer?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I have recently been asked to prove that a part of my program constitutes a layer. 
We all know that the layer is a group of reusable components that are reusable in similar circumstances, but how to empirically prove that a certain piece of code can be described as a 'layer' in terms of software engineering? What makes code, class or type a 'layer'?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120438/whats-the-difference-between-layers-and-tiers

Comment: "We all know that the layer is a group of reusable components that are reusable in similar circumstances."  No.  The essential characteristic of a "layer" is that it *separates* the stuff above it from the stuff below it.